# featured image metabox not moving custom post type

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am working on theme development and I have to move my featured image metabox so that it is more user friendly.  I searched for move featured image metabox.

Thanks Allah for I have found the solution

For a test I found that the problem is that it works for "post" post type not custom post type

***# Information***

WP version: 5.0.3
PHP version: 7.2.11
I am using Laragon

***# This is the code***

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'ppdc_screenshot_move_metabox' );

function ppdc_screenshot_move_metabox() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'ppdc-screenshot', 'side' );
    add_meta_box('postimagediv', 'Screenshot Image', 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'ppdc-screenshot', 'normal', 'high');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code may be help you.

> You can read the full parameters for add_meta_box in the codex. I also
>   listed them here:

```
add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $context, $priority, $callback_args );

function wpt_add_event_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'wpt_events_location',      // $id
        'Event Location',           // $title
        'wpt_events_location',      // $callback
        'events',                   // $page (Post Type)
        'side',                     // $context
        'default'                   // $priority
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpt_add_event_metaboxes' );
```

***For the example above:***

- **$id** is “wpt_events_location”- or the html id that will be applied to
  this metabox.
- **$title** is “Event Location”. This appears at the top of the new
  metabox when displayed.
- **$callback** is the function “wpt_events_location” which will load the
  html into the metabox.
- **$page** is “events”, the name of our custom post type.
- **$context** is “side”. If you wanted it to load below the content area,
  you could put “normal”.
- **$priority** controls where the metabox will display in relation to the
  other metaboxes. You can put “high”, “low” or “default”.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer .. I know how to use `add_meta_box()` function ... I've solve my problem **It was my internet Cache** because I used drag features before I added my metabox so I think my browser forced to stay in the side
but when I clear my all of my browser data ( internet history, cache, session etc ) it's just show up in normal position :D

**This is Solution I've Found**